Typeerror: cannot unpack a nonetype object
class GapStatistics

GapStatEucl = GapStatistics(return_params=True)
optimum, params = GapStatEucl.fit_predict(KMedoids, 15, cluster_vars_gap)

And the error:
      1 GapStatEucl = GapStatistics(return_params=True)
----> 2 optimum, params = GapStatEucl.fit_predict(KMedoids, 15, cluster_vars_gap)

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

How can one resolve this?

don't try to unpack None

You're getting this error because GapStatEucl.fit_predict(KMedoids, 15, cluster_vars_gap) is returning None, which can't be unpacked into multiple values, e.g. optimum, params. As for why it's returning None it's hard to say.

The values are in self.params

It's apparently not returning them. Call the function and then use GapStatEucl.params

"How can one resolve this?" ...first understand what is happening, then work out where you went wrong, then fix it.

If you add the definition of fit_predict() we may be able to tell what you should do.

What do you need help with exactly? Like to start, do you understand what the error means? Your next question might then be "why is fit_predict returning None", which reading the docs should help you answer, though I'm not familiar with this library. For tips, see How to ask a good question.

If it helps: What is a 'NoneType' object? and What does it mean to unpack in python?

I can see for some documentation for something similar here: https://pypi.org/project/gapstatistics/ .
It says that GapStatEucl.fit_predict "returns either the optimal number of clusters (K) or a tuple with the optimal K and additional statistics used in gap analysis".
So I think, in your case, it may be returning just the K value, and not a Tuple. And, the K value may be None, because perhaps the stats module isn't setup correctly. Hence, there is nothing to unpack.
To test what it is returning, simply do this:
print(GapStatEucl.fit_predict(KMedoids, 15, cluster_vars_gap))

And see if it's a Tuple or not. And if SOMETIMES it returns K, and SOMETIMES returns a Tuple, then, you should store the result and test it each time:
optimum = None #To ensure these vars are in scope, define them outside the If block
params = None
result = GapStatEucl.fit_predict(KMedoids, 15, cluster_vars_gap)
if result==None:
    print("Uh oh")
elif isinstance(result, tuple): #Full set of results in a tuple. 
    (optimum, params) = result #Unpack the results into separate vars
else:
    optimum = result #the params will remain as None
    #Do whatever you need to do, to deal with this

